# Jenkins "Pipe is already closed" when copy artifacts to slave

Tags: jenkins

I am trying co setup an Linux slave for Jenkins and it seems that copyartifacts plugin fails to copy artifacts from master (Linux) to slave. It copies some of the files but always fails at last one with exception:

```
ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from metabuilds-build with filter: **
java.io.IOException: Pipe is already closed
    at hudson.remoting.PipeWindow.checkDeath(PipeWindow.java:83)
    at hudson.remoting.PipeWindow$Real.get(PipeWindow.java:165)
    at hudson.remoting.ProxyOutputStream._write(ProxyOutputStream.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.ProxyOutputStream.write(ProxyOutputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:72)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.tar.TarBuffer.writeBlock(TarBuffer.java:410)
    at org.apache.tools.tar.TarBuffer.writeRecord(TarBuffer.java:351)
    at hudson.org.apache.tools.tar.TarOutputStream.writeEOFRecord(TarOutputStream.java:356)
    at hudson.org.apache.tools.tar.TarOutputStream.finish(TarOutputStream.java:137)
    at hudson.org.apache.tools.tar.TarOutputStream.close(TarOutputStream.java:149)
    at hudson.util.io.TarArchiver.close(TarArchiver.java:119)
    at hudson.FilePath.writeToTar(FilePath.java:1619)
    at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1544)
    at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:1473)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.FilePathCopyMethod.copyAll(FilePathCopyMethod.java:51)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact.perform(CopyArtifact.java:225)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact.perform(CopyArtifact.java:199)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:662)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:177)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:429)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1374)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe is already closed
    at hudson.remoting.FastPipedOutputStream.write(FastPipedOutputStream.java:147)
    at hudson.remoting.FastPipedOutputStream.write(FastPipedOutputStream.java:131)
    at hudson.remoting.ProxyOutputStream$Chunk$1.run(ProxyOutputStream.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.FastPipedInputStream$ClosedBy: The pipe was closed at...
    at hudson.remoting.FastPipedInputStream.close(FastPipedInputStream.java:112)
    at hudson.FilePath$32.invoke(FilePath.java:1540)
    at hudson.FilePath$32.invoke(FilePath.java:1534)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:1979)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    ... 6 more
```

Any ideas? We have Jenkins 1.413 and copyartifacts plugin of version 1.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had inapriopriate permissions in the slave directory. In case of anyone needed I will write exactly what I have done:

- At the first time of copy artifacts invocation the error inspired by JENKINS-9540 I updated the copyartifacts plugin to version 1.17 - did not helped.
- After that I tried to pass the build further so I disabled the copyartifacts step and manually uploaded the content to the slave (as root! that introduced bad file permissions for jenkins user)
- When the build succeeded I returned to the main error and updated the plugin to version 1.20. This did not helped, but decided th check if the permissions are OK and noticed that the files I was trying to replace was owned by root.
- After a little chown and chgrp the problem was fixed.

SUMMARY: Check the actual file/directory permissions when such problem occurs first and after that try newer version of the plugin.

Comment: Glad to see that you finally found the reason. :) Please accept _your_ answer so that it doesn't remain in _open_ state.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the plugin. You need to upgrade to a newer version or to the latest version *depending on whether the latest plugin version is compatible with the Jenkins version you have*. Please check the *last two* latest comment in the link: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9540

Comment: Already seen this, thats why I migrated from 1.16 to 1.17 but it did not helped. I cannot update to the newest one because of older Jenkins (newest plugin probabbly won`t be compatible). Moreover when I watch plugin changes log I do not see anything about fixing such error.

Comment: I agree that the change log is not showing this info but we cannot ignore the comments too. :) Did you check the disk space where build is happening? Some people have also mentioned that as one of the reason. If that's not the case, then you can try some other newer version than the one you have and see if it works. `https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/copyartifact/`

Comment: Seen that comment too, the space is not the problem though :( I will probably need to try the newest version as you say and if it fails - rollback the change.

Comment: If the newest one is not compatible with your Jenkins, then it's not going to work although you can give that a try too. You may try any other version which is newer than your current one by downloading it from the link i provided in my last comment. You will have to install it manually though.